# Splunk search query syntax?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

How would I filter my search to select specific ***orderId*** in the **message** field?

**deviceId**:  12345678 
**logLevel**:  INFO 
**message**:  --> GET https://example.myorder.com/orders 
ADRUM_1: isMobile:true 
ADRUM: isAjax:true 
--> END GET 
<-- 200 https://example.myorder.com/orders (974ms) 
date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 22:16:45 GMT 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
x-amzn-requestid: 1234 
x-amz-apigw-id: 8901234 
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-64cef

{"orders":[{"orderId":"99099816588465820255","orderType":"large","orderState":"Ready to Ship","customer":{"firstname":"Stack","surname":"Overflow","email":"example@acme.com","address":{"street1":"23 Elm St","state":"NY","country":"US","city":"New York","postalCode":"10001-1595"}},"orderStateTimestamp":"2022-07-26T15:00:20.617Z","orderCreateTimestamp":"2022-07-26T14:43:01.208Z","batch":{"id":"678-987"}} ... 
<-- END HTTP (725966-byte body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do that.  The first is to simply scan for the orderId in the base search.

`index=foo <<orderId>>`

but that may produce false positives if the order ID value can appear elsewhere.  We can narrow the possibilities to the `message` field this way

`index=foo message="*<<orderId>>*"` OR
`index=foo message="*orderId\":\"<<orderId>>\"*"`

but leading wildcards are terrible for performance.

Examining the `message` field after the base search should reduce the false positives.

```
index=foo
| where match(message, "orderId\\\":\\\"<<orderId>>\\\"")
```

or

```
index=foo
| rex field=message "orderId\\\":\\\"(?<orderId>[^\\\"]+)"
| where orderId == <<orderId>>
```

NB: In all of the examples, `<<orderId>>` should be replaced by the value sought.

Comment: I had to correct **rex field=message "orderId\\\":\\\"(?<orderId>[^\\\"]+)"** but it's looking good so far

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yes. Accepted your answer. Thx!